# Proper set up shared folders for users

Tags: windows, network-share, file-permissions, file-sharing

First I would like to say thanks for helping, and I have huge problem with proper set up permission for shared folders.

I have

- Windows 7 x64 ent. - name: backupfb - added to domain with shared folder on drive e: (e:\backup)
- 50 clients/laptops with TSM Tivoli fastback for workstations who save files on shared folder

And I need to configure proper permission for my shared folders that only owner of folder can access to their folders.

Folder structure is:

`e:\backup` <- shared as a "backup" folder `\\\backupfb\backup\`

`e:\backup\BackupAdmin` <-- directory is used by the Tivoli Storage Manager
FastBack for Workstations client to download revisions and configurations. Nodes
require read-only access to these directories

`e:\backup\RealTimeBackup` <-- enable client accounts to create directories that are only accessible by the account that created them. As a result, the directory that contains data for a node is not created until that node connects to the server.

So permission should look like that (take from instructions):

Inheritable permissions from object`s parents are DISABLE

Permission entries:

```
\\\backupfb\backup\BackupAdmin

* Allow Users Read, Execute This folder, subfolders, and files
                        Traverse Folder / Execute Allow
                        List Folder / Read Data Allow
                        Read Attributes Allow
                        Read Extended Attributes Allow
                        Delete subfolders and files Allow
                        Delete Allow
                        Read Permission’s Allow

* Allow Administrators Full Control This folder, subfolders, and files
```

Both folders have enabled option "apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container only"

Here everything works fine

```
\\\backupfb\backup\RealTimeBackup <<--

Allow Administrators Full Control This folder, subfolders, and files
Allow CREATOR OWNER Full Control This folder, subfolders, and files (from domain)
Allow Users Special This folder only
                Traverse Folder / Execute Allow
                List Folder / Read Data Allow
                Read Attributes Allow
                Read Extended Attributes Allow
                Create Files / Write Data Allow
                Create Folders / Append Data Allow
                Delete subfolders and files Allow
                Read Permission’s Allow

Allow OWNER RIGHTS* Full Control This folder, subfolders, and files
```

Here I have huge problem with CREATOR OWNER I`m able to set FULL CONTROL but I can only apply "Subfolders and files only". When I change props. to "This folder, subfolders and files" and save it`s change to "Subfolders and files only"

So I try use icacls to set up permissions

```
 @echo off

takeown /F E:\backup\ /R /A

for /D %%i IN (E:\backup\RealTimeBackup\*) DO icacls E:\backup\RealTimeBackup\%%~nxi /grant:r cloud\%%~nxi:F /T /C

pause
```

but after that user are able to create just one folder in \backupfb\backup\RealTimeBackup\userfolder but problem is with subfolders

In log i have:

```
FBW5022E Unable to access the specified file Explanation: The file specified is unable to be accessed. Possibly spelled incorrectly, or bad path, or permissions.
User response: Ensure the user has the proper permissions for the file and directories involved andthat the file and directory exist
```

Any idea ?? pls help ;-) thanks

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 as a server? That's going to cause issues (if it hasn't already) due to the file sharing limit in Desktop versions of Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately yes ;-( and i need it to use Win7 as a storage/shared place<br/> is there any whey to do what i need ?? thanks

Comment: You could download and install a trial version of Server 2008 R2/2012 and see if you have the same issue. Trials run for 120 days and can be "re-armed" up to 3 times as far as I can remember.

Comment: ok, so i`ll try with w2k8r2